# Strange behavior of JSON data in Opera

Tags: json, opera

I have a Zend application that returns JSON data. With this data I create a table rows. At this point every thing is ok because I tried on Firefox and Chrome. The problem started when I tried on Opera: don't create the table rows except when I add firebug-lite at my layout head.
Reading a lot I have tried adding an eval function, concatening '(' ')' inside of eval function, changing MIME type of data but nothing seems to work. Also I have same problem with IE.
Thanks for the help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: How do you create the table rows using the data? Show us an example please.

Comment: Sorry, we really need to see a page with this problem - there could be lots of reasons for the failure, and we don't really have enough information here.

Comment: please could you paste here the code or give a link?

Answer (score 1):

Without more data, it is difficult to answer, but in the meantime, if you need to understanding what is happening at the DOM level and how your data are received by Opera, you want to use [dragonfly the Web developer tool](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/).